# Run JavaScript targeting iframe in electron

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, webview, electron

Is it possible to execute JavaScript in either a preload script or manually targeting an iframe in a webview /The webview is based on chrome , my intuition says it should be possible.

Basically I would like to click a button inside the iframe using:

```
document.querySelector('button selector').click();
```

The page looks something like this. (The page is loaded in the webview)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe>
      <button id="foo">Click</button>
    <iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```